# use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 3.1 in .netstandard 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to create a .netstandard 2.1 class library called `SharedLib` and need to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core. Since I have another asp.net core webapi project (called `Server`) targeting .net core 3.1 that uses this `SharedLib` so I am thinking to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core the same version in .netstandard 2.1 project.

However, I can only find 2.2.5 version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core in `SharedLib`. As a result, when I publish the asp.net core webapi project (`Server`)  wit --self-contained, there is an error saying

```
Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
Server -> ShareLib-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.5 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 -> System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0) 
Server -> ShareLib-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.5 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.0.11)
```

Can anyone please help? Thank you

Comment: Does issue only occurs when app is published as self-contained?

Comment: Yes, if it is not self-contained, it can be published successfully